# How can I test a variable as confounding in linear regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, analysis, lm

I'm currently doing the statistical analysis I'm going to use in my article. It's about sleep and some functioning/cognitive measures on mood disorder patients.

The problem I have is: I correlated a functioning score (continuous variable) with a sleep quality score (continuous variable) using Spearman's correlation. It had a significant p-value (p < 0.05).

And now, I would like to test some variables as confounding variables, like years of education (numeric), use of hypnotic and sedatives (dichotomous), suicide risk (dichotomous) and psychotherapeutic/farmacological treatment.

I use R to run all of my analysis. And my advisor said that I should consider confounding variables those associated with exposure and outcome with p-value < 0.20 in the crude analysis, considering a linear regression model.

What I've tried (that I actually don't know if it's correct or not and how should I interpret the output):

```
summary(lm(functioning_score ~ sleep_score + years_of_education + sleep_score*ages_of_education, data = data))
```

```
Call:
lm(formula = functioning_score ~ sleep_score + years_of_education + sleep_score*years_of_education, data = data)

Residuals:

   Min           1Q       Median           3Q          Max 

-29.08309673  -7.39316605  -1.09011226   5.49959525  31.53154265 

Coefficients:

   Estimate    Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)  
 
(Intercept)              7.9339474261  9.4999174669  0.83516 0.4073078 
  
sleep_score               2.1791574956  0.7761289987  2.80773 0.0069287

years_of_education            -0.3209011778  0.8309350862 -0.38619 0.7008713 
  
sleep_score:years_of_education -0.0144874634  0.0746344060 -0.19411 0.8468163   
---

Residual standard error: 11.106846 on 54 degrees of freedom

Multiple R-squared:  0.519259282,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.492551464
 
F-statistic: 19.4422205 on 3 and 54 DF,  p-value: 0.0000000112304043
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: Oh @MrFlick, thank you for the clarification. I'm going to make the post on Cross Validated. Sorry about the mistake, your guidance was helpful! Have a good day!